# ParentFieldValue and COUNT MVL in calculated field: Siebel

Tags: siebel

I want to count child records and using COUNT ("MVL") function in a calculated field. My search spec is like below:

```
[Hearing Date] = ParentFieldValue("Schedule Date") AND [GHQ Session Status] = LookupValue("GHQ_SESSION_STATUS", "Scheduled")
```

My calculated field always gives 0 (zero). I looked into logs and found a straight query:

```
    SELECT
          T10.CONFLICT_ID,
          T10.LAST_UPD,
          T10.CREATED,
          T10.LAST_UPD_BY,
          T10.CREATED_BY,
          T10.MODIFICATION_NUM,
          T10.ROW_ID,
          T9.X_SRL_NUMBER,
          T10.OCCUR_DT,
          T10.X_PAR_JUD_ID,
          T10.X_AUTO_CREATED_FLG,
          T7.NAME,
          T1.FST_NAME,
          T1.JOB_TITLE,
          T1.LAST_NAME,
          T5.POSTN_ID,
          T6.PR_POSTN_ID,
          T2.ATTRIB_03,
          T10.X_REVIEW_FLG,
          T10.X_MP_POSTN_ID,
          T4.X_PANEL_ID,
          T10.X_CASE_ID,
          T10.X_PANEL_ID,
          T10.X_PANEL_SCHED_ID,
          T9.X_REF_NUMBER,
          T9.SERIAL_NUM,
          T10.X_STATUS_CD,
          T10.X_STATUS_CD,
          :1
       FROM 
           SIEBEL.S_CONTACT T1,
           SIEBEL.S_PROJ_XM T2,
           SIEBEL.S_OFFENSE T3,
           SIEBEL.S_INCIDENT T4,
           SIEBEL.S_PROJ_POSTN T5,
           SIEBEL.S_PROJ T6,
           SIEBEL.S_PROJ T7,
           SIEBEL.S_POSTN T8,
           SIEBEL.S_CASE T9,
           SIEBEL.S_INCIDENT T10
       WHERE 
          T10.X_PANEL_SCHED_ID = T2.ROW_ID (+) AND
          T10.X_PANEL_ID = T6.ROW_ID (+) AND
          T10.X_PANEL_ID = T5.PROJ_ID (+) AND T5.X_PANEL_ROLE (+) = 'Head of Bench' AND
          T4.X_PANEL_ID = T7.ROW_ID (+) AND
          T3.INCIDENT_ID = T4.ROW_ID (+) AND
          T10.X_PAR_JUD_ID = T3.ROW_ID (+) AND
          T8.PR_EMP_ID = T1.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
          T10.X_MP_POSTN_ID = T8.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
          T10.X_CASE_ID = T9.ROW_ID (+) AND
          ((T10.X_STATUS_CD IN ( :2 )) AND
          (T10.X_TYPE = 'GHQ Hearing Session')) AND
          (T10.X_PANEL_ID = :3)
       ORDER BY
          T10.X_PANEL_ID DESC, T10.CREATED DESC

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 Bind variable 1: ,,,SADMIN,0000000257bd2d90:0,,GHQ Hearing BC,LHC Roster Roster Detail View

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 Bind variable 2: Scheduled

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 Bind variable 3: 1-12IWRL

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 User search spec: 

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 Named search [Link Search Spec Named Search]: [Hearing Date] = ParentFieldValue("Schedule Date") AND [GHQ Session Status] = LookupValue("GHQ_SESSION_STATUS", "Scheduled")

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 Named search [System Search]: [Type]='GHQ Hearing Session'

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 User sort spec: Created (DESCENDING)

    ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 System sort spec: Panel Id
```

But when I remove **[Hearing Date] = ParentFieldValue("Schedule Date")** part in search spec. Then I get count and below is the generated query:

```
SELECT
      COUNT (*),
      :1
   FROM 
       SIEBEL.S_INCIDENT T1
   WHERE 
      ((T1.X_STATUS_CD IN ( :2 )) AND
      (T1.X_TYPE = 'GHQ Hearing Session')) AND
      (T1.X_PANEL_ID = :3)

ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 Bind variable 1: ,,,SADMIN,0000000257bd1758:0,,GHQ Hearing BC,LHC Roster Roster Detail View

ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 Bind variable 2: Scheduled

ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 Bind variable 3: 1-12IWRL

ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 User search spec: 

ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 Named search [Link Search Spec Named Search]: [GHQ Session Status] = LookupValue("GHQ_SESSION_STATUS", "Scheduled")

ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 Named search [System Search]: [Type] = "GHQ Hearing Session"

ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 User sort spec: 

ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25 System sort spec: 

ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd1758:0  2016-08-24 12:52:25
```

Link specification property is set for all the fields being used in search spec and also on the calculated field. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here or it is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link Specification property on BC field did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in

```
ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   0000000257bd2d90:0  2016-08-24 12:02:44 System sort spec: Panel Id
```

I am assuming this is an Association Sort spec on the link. This causes the system to activate the field `Panel Id`, which adds further tables and conditions into the SQL, restricting data.

Suggestion:Try removing that sort spec and try the original calc field again.

Comment: There is no search spec mentioned on the link.

Comment: Find and remove that searchspec on Panel field.

Comment: I don't have any object named Panel. Are you saying that there is a BC field with named Panel and remove search spec from it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the culprit is:

```
AND T5.X_PANEL_ROLE (+) = 'Head of Bench'
```

Can you check the results of the query after commenting it out?